# Prevent downloading of same JavaScript library multiple times

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs, javascript

I have a scenario in which a container HTML page is including most of the common JS frameworks like JQuery, AngularJS, Bootstrap. This page will then include other widgets in it through Ajax call using JQuery and if those widgets come with any of these common frameworks, the application/events of duplicated framework stopped working.

Now is there any way to prevent downloading of common frameworks from these widgets?

Can this be handled through RequireJS?

Comment: it means complete w3c widget is fetched via AJAX and finally embedded in container HTML page DOM? and you want to white list scripts of widgets?

Comment: @muneebShabbir Yes, you got my problem.

Comment: may be set a flag with sessionStorage

Comment: @Whisher Can you provide some sample code to achieve this using sessionStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the idea:

```
if (!sessionStorage.isLoaded)
{
    //load
    var fileref=document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    fileref.onload = function(){
      sessionStorage.isLoaded = 1;
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

}
```

check for ie compatibility
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/

It's better off to unset sessionStorage.isLoaded
beforeOnLoad :)